# Send Email when Error in ASP.Net MVC 5 using ELMAH

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, web-config, elmah

I am trying to send email whenever there is an exception in my code using **Elmah**. 
Here is the configuration in web.config file.

```
<elmah> 
    <errorMail from="MyEmailId@gmail.com" to="MyEmailId@gmail.com" 
                async="true"  smtpPort="0" useSsl="true" /> 
</elmah>
<system.net> 
    <mailSettings> 
        <smtp deliveryMethod ="Network"> 
            <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" userName="MyEmailId@gmail.com"   password="MyEmailPassword" /> 
        </smtp> 
    </mailSettings> 
</system.net>
```

Now above configuration works fine. I tested in localhost every time I get an exception I am getting an Email Successfully.

**Question 1:**

> Does that mean if I deploy my application with above settings, no
>   matter who ever access my website, if they get an exception I will
>   receive an email.

**Question 2:**

> I have added password in above config file. But now everyone can see
>   my password. Is this the right way or I can still send the mail w/o
>   putting my password in config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Answer to question 1 :

> Exceptions will be caught irrespective of the type of error module you
>   use. So you will definitely receive an email in those exception cases.

## Answer to question 2 :

> Why are you using your personal mail id? Create a new ID and use it
>   for the purpose, so that even if others see, it doesn't have any
>   effect. Others means only the developers will be able to see, not the
>   public. You can encrypt the web.config file by checking this [MSDN
>   article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtkwfdky(v=vs.100).aspx).
>   Also consider encrypting your password and storing it in the
>   web,config file.